# Можно ли использовать тире вместо других знаков препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли используется тире в следующих случаях -

1. Надо подумать - в каком случае ты продолжишь работу над этой задачей.
2. А в каком - нет?
3. Например - если получила удовольствие, то продолжаешь.

(в последнем случае - можно ли использовать тире вместо запятой)

Answer (score 1):

На мой взгляд, тут только во втором случае можно поставить тире (но не требуется).

1. Тут типичный случай для двоеточия: сложное предложение без союзов и вторая часть предложения раскрывает первую.

`Надо подумать: в каком случае ты продолжишь работу над этой задачей.`

2. Перед словом "нет" в конце фразы можно ставить тире, а можно — нет. Это весьма спорный вопрос. На [соседнем стаке о Русском](https://rus.stackexchange.com/) (не спрашивайте почему их два) можно найти [следующий](https://rus.stackexchange.com/a/434079/197493) ответ:

> В данном случае тире обозначает паузу в речи и обычно ставится, но не всегда (зависит от структуры предложения и желания автора).

`А в каком - нет?`

или

`А в каком нет?`

3. Здесь слово "например" играет роль типичного вводного слова и выделяется запятой. Например, можете посмотреть подробное [описание этого правила на Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2).

`Например, если получила удовольствие, то продолжаешь.`